# Drop Down List enhancement for a missing value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, insert

I have a dropdown list that populates from the database

```
<td>    
   <select style="width:100%"class="CounterParty" >
   <?php

      echo '<option selected="selected"></option>';
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(CounterParty)
                             FROM dbo.tbl_hist_transactions
                             ORDER BY CounterParty DESC");
      $stmt->execute();
             while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      echo '<option >'.$row['CounterParty'].'</option>';
             }
    ?>
   </select> 
</td>
```

How can I modify it so that if I have a new Counterparty field that is not present in the field, the user can simply type in the new value. And it is entered in the database.

Thank You.

Comment: You would need to create a form with a textbox, and then write PHP code to take the POST value and insert into your table.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that this is your example dropdown-list:

```
<select class="CounterParty">
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
    <option value="new">New item</option>
</select>
```

If you use a JavaScript library like jQuery, you can add a new item to this dropdown-list dynamically when you select the pseudo-option "New Item" and enter the name of a new one. Here is the example code of it:

```
$('.CounterParty').change( function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'new') {
        var newItem = prompt('Add new item:');

        if(!newItem) return false;

        $(this).append('<option value"' + newItem + '" selected="selected">' + newItem + '</option>');
    }
});
```

After the new item was added and the form has been submitted, the value can be stored in the database like any other value too.

Here is the example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lms1p5a3/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JavaScript/Jquery You can insert the new option by catching it with an `if()` loop The downside from this methode is that it has to refresh the page.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['insert'])){

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `dbo.tbl_hist_transactions` (CounterParty)
    VALUES (:CounterParty)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':CounterParty', $option);

    // insert a row
    $option = $_GET['insert'];
    $stmt->execute();

}
?>


<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <select style="width:100%"class="CounterParty" >
    <?php

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(CounterParty) FROM dbo.tbl_hist_transactions ORDER BY CounterParty DESC");
        $stmt->execute();

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['CounterParty'].'">'.$row['CounterParty'].'</option>';
            }
    ?>
    </select> 
    Add option<input type="text" name="insert"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```